# Can I allow for "breaks" in a for loop with node.js?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, for-loop

I have a massive `for` loop and I want to allow I/O to continue while I'm processing. Maybe every 10,000 or so iterations. Any way for me to allow for additional I/O this way?

Comment: A massive for loop is a counter-pattern to how node is designed. It isn't a thread-per-process style framework.

Comment: @Chance -- that seems to be why he's posting the question.

Comment: @rob yep, but he's asking how to make the for loop work. I'm suggesting that the loop must go ;P.

Comment: @Chance -- ok, I guess I interpreted his question to mean that his current implementation is a for loop, and he's looking for something better (whether it be a for loop or something else)

Answer (score 5):

A massive for loop is just you blocking the entire server.

You have two options, either put the for loop in a new thread, or make it asynchronous.

```
var data = [];
var next = function(i) {
  // do thing with data [i];
  process.nextTick(next.bind(this, i + 1));
};

process.nextTick(next.bind(this, 0));
```

I don't recommend the latter. Your just implementing naive time splicing which the OS level process scheduler can do better then you.

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec

var s = exec("node " + filename, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
  stdout.on("data", function() { 
    // handle data
  });
});
```

Alternatively use something like `hook.io` to manage processes for you.

Actually you probably want to aggressively redesign your codebase if you have a blocking for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this to break your loop into chunks...

Instead of:

```
for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
  doSomething(i);
  }
```

Something like:

```
var i = 0, limit;
while (i < len) {
  limit = (i+10000);
  if (limit > len)
    limit = len;
  process.nextTick(function(){
     for (; i<limit; i++) {
      doSomething(i);
     }
    });
  }
}
```

The nextTick() call gives a chance for other events to get in there, but it still does most looping synchronously which (I'm guessing) will be a lot faster than creating a new event for every iteration.  And obviously, you can experiment with the number (10,000) till you get the results you want.

In theory, you could also use setTimeout() rather than nextTick(), in case it turns out that giving other processes a somewhat bigger "time-slice" helps.  That gives you one more variable (the timeout milliseconds) that you can use for tuning.